# accessing structure in R

Tags: r

I would like to get the names of items based on their cronbach-alpha-if-excluded value.
The ltm package gives me the data I would need but I couldn't understand how to access its resultset in the way I needed. (I know that other packages have Cronbach alpha functions but I could only find this one to handle my random missing data.)

```
library(ltm)
descript(Abortion)['alpha']
```

results in

```
$alpha
                     value
All Items        0.8706719
Excluding Item 1 0.8572997
Excluding Item 2 0.8223116
Excluding Item 3 0.8147668
Excluding Item 4 0.8430359
```

I would like to order them according to the return value and put the item names of the two largest in a list. In this case I would need a way to return badItems<-c('Item 1', 'Item 4').

How could I do that?

Comment: Is this what you mean? names(sort(descript(Abortion)['alpha']$alpha[-1,1], decreasing=TRUE)[c(1,2)])

Comment: @user1981275 why don't you post that as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
names(sort(descript(Abortion)['alpha']$alpha[-1,1], decreasing=TRUE)[c(1,2)])
```

Comment: This was it exactly.
Only needed to extract the item names.

pat <- "Excluding (.*)$";
bad_item_list=names(sort(descript(Abortion)['alpha']$alpha[-1,1], decreasing=TRUE)[c(1,2)])
sub(pat, "\\1", bad_item_list[grepl(pat, bad_item_list)])